# iOS 5.0 issues - The existing app on iTunes store is crashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5

So many applications which are uploaded on iTune Store have issues with iOS 5.0.

Recently I have uploaded two applications which both have issues with iOS 5.0 and most one is crashing application on iOS 5.0.

During debugging application in iOS 5.0, The control transfers to main.m file and pointed to  the  below line,

`int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

There are also problems with UI, and it look like the view hierarchy changed for new iOS 5.0 will crash most of apps from older version.

Also the application is not crashing on simulator but it crashes on device.

Please give your suggestions to overcome from issues of iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

Use workspace breakpoints for all exceptions ("on throw") and a symbolic breakpoint for the "abort" symbol. this will show you exactly where your app crashes.